# How to change the color of bottom navigation bar tap animation?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

As you can see in this gif: https://gyazo.com/fc2f8e8ae9fbdae1b06d88336e76bc05

When an icon is tapped, an animation is played which is a green color. By default this color is gray. How can I change it to a different color?

Comment: The gif is gone!

Answer (score 5):

For ripples you can specify `colorControlHighlight` for API 21 or higher.

Add this line to your `res/values-v21/styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="...">
        ...
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">[desired color]</item>
        ...
    </style>
</resources>
```

Replace `[desired color]` with your color, or a color resource, such as `#009688` or `@color/color_control_highlight`. That'll default all ripple animations to the desired color.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with your event. Like when you click the event then change source or transparent color of bottom bar actions.

Changing drawable can be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `app:itemBackground="@null"` in XML.